# How can I vertically align text in my footer and also remove underline from ::after content

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

So I have two questions:

### 1. How can I vertically align text in my footer with two or more lines?

(I'm justing line-height with the height of footer to align one line but it leaves huge gaps between two or more lines)

### 2. How can I remove underline from CSS ::after content thing but keep it under the text.

(so all Links will look on hover like the last one)

***HTML & CSS***

```css
    footer {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
      color: white;
      background-color: #232323;
    }
    
    footer a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    footer a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    footer a:not(:last-child)::after {
      content: " | ";
      cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
    <a>Link</a>
</footer>
```

***JSFIDDLE***
https://jsfiddle.net/qmbbtmb5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qmbbtmb5/2/ for the underline

Comment: @TemaniAfif It still doesn't remove underline from that content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work like you want by adding `position: absolute` css property to the `:after` pseudo selector. Try adjusting your css code like this one.

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: #232323;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

footer a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer a:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: " | ";
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Do you have any idea how to fix my first problem?

Comment: I added top and bottom `padding` and reduced your `line-height` to make your footer links align vertically middle.

Comment: Oh, I missed that because I just copied last CSS rule. Thanks a lot!